# How to solve PUT method is not allowed in drf?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've a model:

```
class ListingPrice(Timestamps):    
    price = models.ForeignKey("Price", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey("location", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["price", "location"]

class Price(Timestamps):

    package = models.ForeignKey("products.Package", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField("location", through="ListingPrice")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=3)
```

with a serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = LocalizedField()

    class Meta:
        model = location
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locations = LocationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Price
        fields = ['package', 'locations', 'price']
        def create(self, validated_data):
             print("validated_data, validated_data)
```

and viewset:

```
class PriceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Price.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
    ordering = ['id']
    permissions = {
        "GET": ["view_minimum_listing_price", ],
        "POST": ["add_minimum_listing_price", ],
        'PUT': ['update_minimum_listing_price', ],
        'DELETE': ['delete_minimum_listing_price', ],
    }
```

In testing I'mm using the following:

```
data = {
            "price": 15,
        }

response = self.client.put(path=self.url, data=data, format='json', args=[1])
```

I'm trying to update the price in the instance with id 1, but neither put or update is not allowed? How to overcome this and update it?

edit: urls.py

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('listing_price', PriceViewSet, basename='listing_price')
```

Comment: Please show your `urls.py`. Maybe you have attached your ViewSet incorrectly?

Comment: @Eugenij added to the description. thanks

Comment: your url should be some thing like   http://127.0.0.1:8000/listing_price/1/   ( protocol:<host-name>/listing_price/<id>/